# How to determine Isomorphism of Non-Symmetric Matrix when Permutation-Set is given?

Tags: algorithms, graphs, matrices, permutations

Consider, two  $m \times n$ matrices $A, B$ such that  there is a permutation $\kappa$ that  such that such that $A^{\kappa}=B$  *(Wielandt's notation)*, i.e. $A, B$ are *isomorphic* but not equal.

Since, permutations of rows are independent of   permutations of columns, so $\kappa = \sigma \pi$ where $\sigma$ is a row permutation that acts on rows of non-symmetric matrix and $\pi$ acts on columns of matrix.

A set of column-permutations $\beta_k$  is a subset of the set of  all possible permutations of columns of $A$. So, $\beta_k \subseteq S_n$.

A set of column-permutations $\gamma_k$  is a subset of the set of  all possible permutations of columns of $B$. So, $\gamma_k \subseteq S_n$.

We consider 2 different set due to different labeling of columns in $A, B$ .

$\pi$ is in the set $\beta_k, \gamma_k$  but with different label.

**Problem:** $A,B, \beta_k, \gamma_k$ are given where  $A \neq B$ and $\sigma$ is unknown.

How can we show that A and B are isomorphic using $\beta_k, \gamma_k$ ?

In other words, can we construct an algorithm to show $A, B$ are isomorphic?

**Edit:**

1. Consider that $\beta_k \subset S_n$ instead of $\beta_k \subseteq S_n$ where size of $\beta_k$ is not as big as exponential.
2. Note that we can $partition$ sets of permutation $\beta_k, \gamma_k$ based on $automorphism$ of matrices $A, B$.

   ***Some help will be appreciated !***

Comment: What if $\beta_k = S_n$? Then you get bipartite graph isomorphism, which is GI-complete. Also, what do you mean by "construct an algorithm to show $A,B$ are isomorphic"? Do you mean an algorithm which finds $\kappa$ given the promise that it exists?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus , 1.yes then it is , GI complete.  2. " Do you mean an algorithm which finds κ given the promise that it exists?" - yes, thought  we have no idea about $\kappa$, we only know about a set of  column permutations, $\beta_k$ . because id you find the $\pi$ or a permutation that arranges columns of  one matrix exactly like another,  then you can find $\kappa$ or a permutation , that arranges rows of matrix exactly like  $\kappa$.

Comment: What do you mean by "the size of $\beta_k$ is not as big as exponential"? What exact bound do you have in mind? This is important, since by padding we can make $\beta_k$ much smaller than all of $S_n$ while not changing the problem at all.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus $|\beta_k|=|\gamma_k| \leq n^{\log(n)}$, I am actually not worried about size. I have a procedure to generate the permutation sets. In the procedure size varies from polynomial to quasipolynomial.  I am more  concerned about the algorithm/solution than the size. Please, note that you can $partition$  $\beta_k, \gamma_k$ based on automorphism of $A,B$. What kind of padding are you referring to?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus ,Would you please confirm this observation:Though **we have different labeling for $\pi$ in $\beta_k, \gamma_k$**, $\pi$ in $\beta_k$  will change the position of some unique columns  (If in a matrix, there exists  one  column which has no similar columns   in that matrix, then that column is an Unique Column) of $A$ to the same position exactly as  $\pi$ in $\gamma_k$  will do in $B$.

Comment: .For example,if $\pi$ in $\beta_k$   changes  the column of $1^{st}$  position  to the  column of $6^{th}$  positionof $A$   then   $\pi$ in $\gamma_k$  will change  the column of $1^{st}$  position  to the  column of $6^{th}$  position  in $B$.Thus we can find/distinguish  $\pi$  or an automorphism of $A^{\pi}$in both $\beta_k, \gamma_k$.

Comment: By padding I mean adding a large (polynomial size) independent set. This shows that we can always assume that $\beta_k \leq (n^\epsilon)!$.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus   .  ok, any comment on the observation?

Comment: The hard case is when there aren't any unique columns.

Comment: :) is it ?, then all permutations of $\beta_k, \gamma_k$ will do the same transformation as $\pi$ does! since $\pi$ is an isomor:, so we need to think about row permutation, it becomes close to a trivial case! so, please, confirm when matrices has unique column.

Comment: No. It's like graph isomorphism for regular graphs. If you *fix* the row permutation, you can easily find the column permutation by sorting the columns.

Comment: "If you fix the row permutation, you can easily find the column permutation by sorting the columns" - yes, but since we have column per:, we will do the reverse once we find the $\pi$ or a perm: which is an auto: of $A^{\pi}$, can we do that given there are unique column(s)?

Comment: You haven't formally defined what unique columns here, but I can say that this approach has been tried in GI, and doesn't always work.

Comment: $\textit{Unique Column :}$  If in a matrix, there exists  one  column which has no similar column   in that matrix, regardless any row  permutation , then that column is an Unique Column. $\textit{Example:}$ In the  matrix $ \mathcal{A}$, $2^{nd}$  column  is  unique. In the $ \mathcal{B}$, $3^{rd}$ column  is unique.
$$\mathcal{A}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 0\\0 & 1 & 0\\
\end{array} \right) ,
 \mathcal{B}=\left( \begin{array}{ccc}
0 & 0 & 0 \\0 & 0 & 1\\0 & 0 & 0\\ \end{array} \right) $$ RE:Note that: $\beta_k , \gamma_k$ have same permutations with different label.

Comment: When the graphs are regular there is no unique columns. This approach can be improved, but has been shown not to work in general. I suggest reviewing the GI literature.

Comment: Posted now on cstheory.se: http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/34815/finding-similar-permutation-from-a-given-set-where-permutation-are-labelled-diff.

Comment: @YuvalFilmus , I asked this on chat but you seem  to be reluctant to go on chat. so I am writing it here: 
Please note that general GI problem does not have a given permutation set. I am not disagreeing with you that there could be a situation when "there is no unique columns" , for example all 1's matrix. But in that case, whatever column permutation you apply, the matrix would be same! So it does not matter which permutation you choose! Is it a wrong observation?